# Fails Brew Elasticsearch Failed

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

Upgraded to V7 yesterday via Brew now ES won't start:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction; support was removed in 14.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly; support was removed in 14.0
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:95)
```

Tried to reinstall and updated the Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crazy issue that I finally tracked down - I hope this helps someone else.  Edit this file:

`/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

```
# JDK 9+ GC logging
9-:-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
# due to internationalization enhancements in JDK 9 Elasticsearch need to set the provider to COMPAT otherwise
# time/date parsing will break in an incompatible way for some date patterns and locals
9-:-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT
```

Then create the `/usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log` file.  Restart ES via brew (`brew services restart elasticsearch`) and you are good to go